# Laravel Vite configuration for separating assets (CSS and images)

Tags: laravel, eloquent, vite, laravel-vite

I have one application where I want to separate my asset folders in Vite configuration.

This is how my current vite.config.js look like. I want something like

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import laravel from 'laravel-vite-plugin';

export default defineConfig({
    build: {
        assetsDir: './images'
    },
    plugins: [
        laravel({
            input: [
                'resources/css/app.css,'
                'resources/scss/app.scss',
                'resources/js/app.js',
            ],
            refresh: true,
        }),
    ],
});
```

I want to separate all images and CSS after the build. For instance

Build - Assets - images (all images will be going)

Build - Assets - Css (all CSS will be going)

Comment: refresh: true,
            // Override the default assets directory for CSS files
            css: {
                assetsDir: './css',
            },